# Firewall does not let me ssh into server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall

I am trying to access my Ubuntu 16.04 server which is online, but the issue I run into is:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Operation timed out
```

I reenabled the firewall prior so I believe the issue has to do with that. Is there any way for me to resolve the issue remotely? I would appreciate any help into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any out-of-band access to your server? If so, then use that to fix the firewall rules. If not, you're sunk.